# Симуляция нажатия кнопки клавиатуры на hardware уровне

Tags: python, клавиатура, поиск-библиотек

Можно ли сделать в Python'е так, чтобы симулировалось нажатие, как на hardware-устройстве. Возможно есть какая-то библиотека, которая позволяет сделать что-то подобное.

Если есть какая-то информация или статьи, пожалуйста поделитесь.

Comment: Пользовательские приложения (обычные приложения - которые не ядро системы, не драйвера, не модули ядра) на любом языке программирования не имеют доступа к устройствам на hardware уровне. Опишите конкретно, какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить.

Comment: Ага, спасибо за конкретику.

Comment: Не за что. Конкретика нужна от вас: без уточнения вопроса ответ будет один - никак.

Comment: @insolor, в целом мне достаточно ответа, который вы дали. Если хотите конкретику, хочу попробовать себя в написания бота для MMO, и нажатие виртуальных клавиш клавиатуры/мыши будет  заметная античитом... Вероятно заметная

Answer (score 0):

Есть библиотека pyautogui. Она позволяет передвигать курсор,узнавать координаты курсора, нажимать правой или левой кнопкой мыши.
Также в ней можно осуществлять ввод текста/определённых комбинаций клавиш, в общем, скорее всего это то, что Вам нужно.
[Здесь небольшое руководство](https://webfanat.com/article_id/?id=137)

Comment: Не то чтобы это то что мне нужно, я не уверен, что нажатие клавиши hardware клавиатуры будет равносильно нажатию клавиши клавиатуры при помощи функции, которая заложена в этой библиотеке.

Comment: На уровне, на котором я использовал эту библиотеку, разницы я не заметил.

Comment: П.С. Если скорость передвижения мышки всегда одинаковая/пауза между нажатиями одинаковая, то браузер очень быстро прерывает работу, распознавая бота.